# I have a component I want to appear once the timer is done

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have my component CountDownSquare I want to disappear once the timer is done fully counting down. I have Data in homePageData that holds the main text in a h3 element, this text should appear once the timer is fully done. Here's a ternary statement I attempt to assign but it isn't assigned to anything the way I thought it would be. Here is a snippet of what I thought of

````
  const { homePageData } = props;
  {homePageData[0].showCountdown ? <CountDownSquare/>: styles.homeBody}


  return (
    homePageData && (
      <Layout>
        <div className={styles.Home}>
          <Image src={wordmark} alt="Hammer and Hope wordmark" />
            <CountDownSquare >
          </CountDownSquare>    
          {/* <div className={styles.homeBody}>
          <h3 className={styles.mainText}>{homePageData[0].mainText}</h3>  */}
            <Nav />
          </div>
      </Layout>
    )
  );
}  ```
````

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming `homePageData[0].showCountDown` is a boolean which is true if the countdown is complete in the parent component.

You need to add conditions while rendering your component.

The following snippet will render the `CountDownSquare` component and the h3 tag with `homePageData[0].mainText` if `homePageData[0].showCountdown` is true.

```
  const { homePageData } = props;

  return (
        homePageData ?? (
        <Layout>
            <div className={styles.Home}>
            <Image src={wordmark} alt="Hammer and Hope wordmark" />
                {homePageData[0].showCountdown ?? 
                    <CountDownSquare >
                    </CountDownSquare>    
                    <div className={styles.homeBody}>
                        <h3 className={styles.mainText}>{homePageData[0].mainText}</h3> 
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </Layout>
        )
    );
```

Comment: I need my countdownsquare to hide & only show the elements underneath once that data is true. This here renders both together.